# Still confused about model.train()

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, torchvision

I read all the posts here regarding `model.train()` and still didn't understand what is up with it. Specifically, when I use a pre-trained model like DenseNet or VGG with all parameters frozen beside the last layer not using drop-out nor Batch Normalization, the training loss starts off a lot smaller when using `model.train()`, but then decreases at about the same rate as when without it.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just three options: just `model(inputs)`, `model.train()(inputs)` and `model.eval()(inputs)`. The only difference is, that when using `.eval()` all the dropout and normalization is ignored because its just used for training and not for tesing.

Now you asked why it is still training when you just use `model(inputs)`? Because when you dont use `train()` nor `eval()` the model will be automatically in train-mode. So `model(inputs)` is the same as `model.train()(inputs)`.